# Is my PyTorch code for fine-tuning a BERT model on a question-answering task correct? How do I save, load, and test the model in a different file?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I've been working on a PyTorch code to fine-tune a BERT model for a question-answering task. Could you give it a quick look to see if it's on the right track? Because, my test code (test.py) is giving me "[cls]" as the output, and I'm not sure why. Any help understanding why the model is doing this and how to fix it would be awesome. Thanks!

**Train.py**

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import transformers
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForQuestionAnswering, AdamW, get_linear_schedule_with_warmup
import pandas as pd
import re

transformers.logging.set_verbosity_error()



# Sample questions and answers
df = pd.read_csv('counsel_chat.csv')

questions = df['questionText'].tolist()
answers = df['answerText'].tolist()

def clean_text(text):

    text = str(text)
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r"i'm", "i am", text)
    text = re.sub(r"he's", "he is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"she's", "she is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"it's", "it is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"that's", "that is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"what's", "that is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"where's", "where is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"how's", "how is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ll", " will", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ve", " have", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'re", " are", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'d", " would", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'re", " are", text)
    text = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"can't", "cannot", text)
    text = re.sub(r"n't", " not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"n'", "ng", text)
    text = re.sub(r"'bout", "about", text)
    text = re.sub(r"'til", "until", text)
    text = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|]", "", text)
    text = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", text)
    text = " ".join(text.split())
    return text

# Clean the data
clean_questions = [clean_text(question) for question in questions]
clean_answers = [clean_text(answer) for answer in answers]

# Create a dataset class
class QADataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, questions, answers, tokenizer, max_length=128):
        self.questions = questions
        self.answers = answers
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.questions)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        question = str(self.questions[idx])
        encoding = self.tokenizer(
            question,
            self.answers[idx],
            max_length=self.max_length,
            padding="max_length",
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        )
        return {
            "input_ids": encoding["input_ids"].squeeze(),
            "attention_mask": encoding["attention_mask"].squeeze(),
            "start_positions": torch.tensor(0),  
            "end_positions": torch.tensor(0)  
        }

num_epochs = 10  # Adjust as needed

# Create dataset and dataloader using cleaned data
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
dataset = QADataset(clean_questions, clean_answers, tokenizer)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)

# Load pre-trained BERT model for question answering
model = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

# Set up optimizer and learning rate scheduler
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)
scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps=0, num_training_steps=len(dataloader) * num_epochs)

# Training loop
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)



for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0.0
    for batch in dataloader:
        # Move batch to device
        batch = {key: value.to(device) for key, value in batch.items()}

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(**batch)
        loss = outputs.loss
        total_loss += loss.item()


        # Backward pass
        loss.backward()

        # Update parameters and scheduler
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    print(("="*20 )+ "\n" + ("="*20))
    average_loss = total_loss / len(dataloader)
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Average Loss: {average_loss}")
    print(("="*20 )+ "\n" + ("="*20))




# Save the fine-tuned model
tokenizer.save_pretrained("fine_tuned_model")
model.save_pretrained("fine_tuned_model")
```

**Test.py**

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import transformers
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForQuestionAnswering
import pandas as pd
import re

transformers.logging.set_verbosity_error()

# Sample questions and answers
df = pd.read_csv('counsel_chat.csv')

questions = df['questionText'].tolist()
answers = df['answerText'].tolist()

def clean_text(text):
    '''Clean text by removing unnecessary characters and altering the format of words.'''
    text = str(text)
    text = text.lower()
    text = re.sub(r"i'm", "i am", text)
    text = re.sub(r"he's", "he is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"she's", "she is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"it's", "it is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"that's", "that is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"what's", "that is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"where's", "where is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"how's", "how is", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ll", " will", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'ve", " have", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'re", " are", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'d", " would", text)
    text = re.sub(r"\'re", " are", text)
    text = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"can't", "cannot", text)
    text = re.sub(r"n't", " not", text)
    text = re.sub(r"n'", "ng", text)
    text = re.sub(r"'bout", "about", text)
    text = re.sub(r"'til", "until", text)
    text = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|]", "", text)
    text = re.sub(r"[-()\"#/@;:<>{}`+=~|.!?,]", "", text)
    text = " ".join(text.split())
    return text

# Clean the data
clean_questions = [clean_text(question) for question in questions]
clean_answers = [clean_text(answer) for answer in answers]

# Create a dataset class
class QADataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, questions, answers, tokenizer, max_length=128):
        self.questions = questions
        self.answers = answers
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.questions)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        question = str(self.questions[idx])
        encoding = self.tokenizer(
            question,
            self.answers[idx],
            max_length=self.max_length,
            padding="max_length",
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        )
        return {
            "input_ids": encoding["input_ids"].squeeze(),
            "attention_mask": encoding["attention_mask"].squeeze(),
            "start_positions": torch.tensor(0),
            "end_positions": torch.tensor(0)
        }

# Create dataset and dataloader using cleaned data
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
dataset = QADataset(clean_questions, clean_answers, tokenizer)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)

# Load fine-tuned BERT model for question answering
model = BertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("fine_tuned_model")

# Testing loop
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)
model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
    for batch in dataloader:
        # Move batch to device
        batch = {key: value.to(device) for key, value in batch.items()}

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(**batch)
        start_logits = outputs.start_logits
        end_logits = outputs.end_logits

        # Get the candidate answers
        candidate_answers = []
        for i, start_logit in enumerate(start_logits[0]):
            for j, end_logit in enumerate(end_logits[0]):
                if i <= j and j - i < 10:  # Limiting the maximum span length
                    candidate_answers.append((i, j, start_logit + end_logit))

        # Select the candidate with the highest probability and above a certain threshold
        threshold = 1.2

        if candidate_answers:
            filtered_candidates = [(start, end, score) for start, end, score in candidate_answers if score > threshold]

            if str(filtered_candidates):
                start, end, _ = max(filtered_candidates, key=lambda x: x[2])
                answer = tokenizer.decode(batch["input_ids"][0][start:end+1].cpu().numpy())
                if all(token in [tokenizer.cls_token_id, tokenizer.sep_token_id, tokenizer.pad_token_id] for token in answer):
                    answer = "No answer found"

            else:
                answer = "No answer found"
        else:
            answer = "No answer found"

        print("Question:", tokenizer.decode(batch["input_ids"][0].cpu().numpy(), skip_special_tokens=True))
        print("Answer:", answer)
        print("="*50)
```